# Is it necessary to add a minimal code to question when self-answering?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, code

Besides being beneficial to people, it is also useful for future me to add here my problem I encountered and its solution (not existing in GIS SE) as a question and answer. I frequently find myself here to get a solution for a problem I solved before, because it is easier to find the answer here than on my computer.

You also know that it is [explicitly encouraged in SE](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to ask and answer your own questions. On the other hand, it is required to provide the shortest code attempts when seeking help to write code. But I don't remember how the code looked like before I had solved.

In this case, should it be included the minimal code in the question body, or could the absence of the code be a reason to close the question?

Comment: "because it is easier to find the answer here than on my computer." I can see myself in that piece of sentence! I would say, for the future you, it's also good to also add a MWE, trust me...

Answer (score 6):

When voting to close I assess each question on its merits but I also try to place it within the context of its Q&A as presented at that time.

I may or may not vote to close a self-answered question like the one you describe depending on its actual content but:

- it sounds like one that I would not vote to close
- even if I or others did, being closed only prevents new answers being added so as long as the community thinks the Q&A is useful (i.e. it attracts upvotes) it will remain on the site and serve the purpose you seek from it.

I think it is better for a self-answered question to contain a code snippet (and error message) that illustrates where you got stuck, before your self-answer contains a code snippet that illustrates how you solved your problem, but I can envisage situations where this might not be possible.